# Ajax in Visual Studio 2013 undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net, mvc, undefined

uso VS 2013, tengo una tabla que debería mostrar los datos de un formulario, pero muestra undefined
HomeController

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddUser(string UserName, string Email, string Password)
    {
        var user = new UserModel();

        user.UserName = UserName;
        user.Email = Email;
        user.Password = Password;

        return Json(user, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

UserModel

```
public class UserModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

}
```

Index

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@model AjaxTut.Models.UserModel

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-offset-4">
        <h2>Add User</h2>
        <br />

        <span>User Name: </span> @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })<br />
        <span>Email: </span> @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })<br />
        <span>Password: </span> @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })<br />
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" onclick='SaveUser()'>Save</a></p> <br /><br /><br />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-offset-3">
        <h2>New User List</h2>
        <table id="myTable" class="table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th>User Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Password</th>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>

<style>
    #myTable tr th {
        color: white;
        width: 300px;
        height: 40px;
        text-decoration: solid;
        background-color: yellowgreen;
        padding: 10px;
    }
</style>

<script>
    function SaveUser() {
        var userName = $("#UserName").val();
        var email = $("#Email").val();
        var password = $("#Password").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            ur: "Home/AddUser",
            data: JSON.stringify({ UserName: userName, Email: email, Password: password }),
            contentType: "application/json",

            success: function (result) {
                $("#myTable").append("<tr><td>" +
                result.UserName + "</td><td>" +
                result.Email + "</td><td>" +
                result.Password + "</td></tr>");

                $("#UserName").val("");
                $("#Email").val("");
                $("#Password").val("");
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

¿Alguien me puede decir qué es lo que pasa?

Comment: Te vas a odiar a vos mismo pero tenes un typo en `ur: "Home/AddUser",` te falta la `l`

Comment: Yo no veo el error, podes aclararlo?

Comment: Cierto, faltaba la l en url... sin embargo, al darle al botón no hace nada

Comment: @hardkoded me pueden recomendar algo?

Answer (score 1):

```
   [HttpPost]
   public JsonResult AddUser(string UserName, string Email, string Password)
   { 
    var user = new UserModel();
    user.UserName = UserName;
    user.Email = Email;
    user.Password = Password;
    return Json(user, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Solucion cambiar ActionResult por JsonResult en el controlador y agregar en la vista

url: "Home/AddUser"

Y a funcionar